# power bi date and time relationship

Tags: powerbi

If I have 2 tables containg datetime field.
One tables' datetime field contains value like 01-01-2017 00:00:00 (only one value for one date and same time as 00:00:00)
Second tables' datetime field contains value like 01-01-2017 11:30:00 (there can be multiple values for one date and different time)

Now, the problem is if create 2 different charts from these 2 tables with datetime field on x axis. and select one date from first tables' chart: 2nd tables' chart is not getting updated by only selected datetime field on x axis. it is showing all datetime field and just highlighting selected datetime data.

I want to show only selected datetime data in 2nd chart.

Please help!

Comment: Drop the time component from the second table, obviously. Or add a copy of that date column with just the date and use that in relationship.

Comment: @user5226582 As I want to show 2nd chart time wise, I can not drop that component. And Second option is already I am doing. That is why it is showing at least that data highlighted! but I need to show that highlighted data only in 2nd chart.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question. Maybe show some screenshots or something. Maybe play around with filter direction in the relationship properties.